# Write-Host not working when startet from cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have simple script

```bsh
Write-Host "asdasd"
```

When I launch it with `powershell.exe -Version 5 -executionpolicy remotesigned -File ./script.ps1`
it shows an error that `Write-Host` cannot be found?

```sh
Program 'Write-Host' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt script.ps1:1 char:1
+ Write-Host "asdasd"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At script.ps1:1 char:1
+ Write-Host "asdasd"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

This happened suddenly, and was not a problem before?

Comment: I think you run with a profile that lacks the modułu Microsoft.Powershell.Utility. do you have modul use 'Get-Module -Name Microsoft.Powershell.Utility' –

Comment: I have this module. This is really strange...

Comment: Replacing `Write-Host` with `Write-Output` suddenly works

Comment: restart the computer :D

Comment: Doesnt work. Either windows or any other software ...?

Comment: `powershell.exe -c "Get-Command Write-Host"` resolved in a `Write-Host` empty file under `C:/Windows/system32/` dont know how this happened.

Comment: `(Get-Module | where Name -Like *Utility* | %{$_.ExportedCommands} ).'WRITE-HOST'`

show me -> `cat $PSHOME\powershell.config.json`